# Don't work file transfer (xep 0234, 0065)

Tags: iphone, xmpp

I am developing an application for the iPhone. I will implement a chat with GoogleTalk XMPP in our application. I want to transfer files using SOCKS5 Bytestream (http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0234.html # hash).
I can not initialize the session. I send request "session-initiate".

```
<jingle xmlns='urn:xmpp:jingle:1'
          action='session-initiate'
          initiator='romeo@montague.lit/orchard'
          sid='851ba2'>
      <content creator='initiator' name='a-file-offer'>
```

The server returns an error "code= 503 service-unavailable".

Could you tell what the problem is? Can I access this service? What other way I can implement a file transfer using GoogleTalk XMPP?

Answer (score 0):

Did you wrap this in an IQ stanza?  If not, that's the problem, but I'm surprised you didn't just get disconnected.  If you did, then check that the `to` address is correct; error 503 can either be a routing error, or can be returned from a receiving client that doesn't implement the protocol in question.

Comment: Thank you for an answer! I found one error - there was not attribute 'dstaddr'. Now a server returns an error - code = 501 feature-not-implemented. May  a problem be  in the account settings?